# CI: Use view/controller in another included view?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to CI & PHP.

I have an [auth library](http://programmersvoice.com/codeigniter/building-a-cms-in-codeigniter-part-2-set-up) included, and works great stand-alone.

I simply want to have the login form load as a view inside another view...is that weird?:

I'm quasi-templating:

index:

```
$this->load->view('head_content');
$this->load->view('stuff');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Inside the stuff view:

```
<stuff></>
$this->load->view('login_view');
<morestuff></>
```

I just want the login form to show up on the front page, and then tie into the auth system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the login view in the controller, and then pass the data to the stuff view.

In the controller:

```
$this->load->view('head_content');
// the line below will save the output of the login view to $data['login']
// instead of outputting to the screen
$data['login'] = $this->load->view('login_view', '', TRUE);
$this->load->view('stuff');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

In the stuff view:

```
<stuff>
<?php echo $login; ?>
<morestuff>
```

Comment: There is something within the controller for this library that keeps me from loging in from any other page but the actual login view...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused myself...
Basically, this didn't work. When I try to login with this lib, it just redirects me to the actual login page...I really have no idea what to say!  Perhaps you can take a look at the link?

Answer (score 0):

In the page [Views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), at the bottom, check out the section **Returning views as data**

Answer (score 0):

I've just recommended this but I'm going to recommend it again:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/77279/
Django-like template inheritance helper for CodeIgniter.

I use this on ALL of my CI projects and it makes things like this stupidly easy.